# Async method to return true or false in a Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I know that an `async` method can only return `void` or `Task`. I have read similar methods for Exception handling inside `async` methods. And I'm new to `async` programming so I am looking for a straightforward solution.

My `async` method runs an Sql query. If the query was ok, it should notify the caller with a Boolean `true` and otherwise a `false`. My method is currently a void so I have no way of knowing.

```
private async void RefreshContacts()
{
    Task refresh = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            // run the query
        }
        catch { }
    }
    );
    await refresh;           
}
```

I simply would like to change `async` to `Task` so that in my `catch` statement the method will return a `false` and otherwise a `true`.

Answer (score 28):

It sounds like you just need to return a `Task<bool>` then:

```
private async Task<bool> RefreshContactsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch // TODO: Catch more specific exceptions
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Personally I would not catch the exception, instead letting the caller check the task for a faulted state, but that's a different matter.

Comment: When I change my catch to `catch { return false; }` after changing my return type to `Task<bool>` I got this warning message: "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

Comment: Checking the Task for a faulted state sounds more interesting, can you bring a simple example?

Comment: @Pedram: Well where do you get that warning, and have you tried following its advice? As for checking the task for a faulted state - see the documentation for `Task`. Although if you await the task, the exception will be rethrown instead.

Comment: The warning appears everywhere I have called the method `RefreshContacts()` If I add await before every call, does that mean I should change all the functions that run this function to async?

Comment: @Pedram: Yes. It sounds like you fundamentally need to take a step back and think about what it means to refresh the contacts asynchronously...

Answer (score 13):

Change the method signature to `Task<bool>`. Then if your method is declared as async you can simple return a bool value. But as jon skeet said there are other, possibly better ways, to handle your szenario

```
 private async Task<bool> RefreshContacts()
    {
        Task refresh = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                // run the query
                      return true;
        }
        catch { return false;}      
}
```

PS: Another common issue you will possibly have is if you have a method without async. Then you can return `Task.FromResult(true)` like this:

```
 private Task<bool> RefreshContacts()
 {
     ....
    return Task.FromResult(true)
 }
```

Comment: When I change my catch to `catch { return false; }` after changing my return type to `Task<bool>` I got this warning message: "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

Comment: This message has nothing to do with the catch statement. Most likely, you don't have any asynchronous calls in the `try` part. In which case, there is no point in using `async` or Tasks.

Comment: The first `RefreshContacts` version doesn't compile. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but I think y'all misleading people here.
See the Microsoft article, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types).

Very simple example which shows how we can return a (scalar) value of `bool`, `int` or `string` type from a Task.

I am posting the C# code here, for posterity:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ShowTodaysInfo().Result);
   }

   private static async Task<string> ShowTodaysInfo()
   {
      string ret = $"Today is {DateTime.Today:D}\n" +
                   "Today's hours of leisure: " +
                   $"{await GetLeisureHours()}";
      return ret;
   }

   static async Task<int> GetLeisureHours()  
   {  
       // Task.FromResult is a placeholder for actual work that returns a string.  
       var today = await Task.FromResult<string>(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString());  

       // The method then can process the result in some way.  
       int leisureHours;  
       if (today.First() == 'S')  
           leisureHours = 16;  
       else  
           leisureHours = 5;  

       return leisureHours;  
   }  
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       Today is Wednesday, May 24, 2017
//       Today's hours of leisure: 5
// </Snippet >
```

Answer (score 0):

google brought me here for a different question so I will answer what I was looking for in hopes that it helps someone else.

In the first example, the async keyword is missing creating a compiler error

```
        protected override Task<bool> ShouldMakeADecision()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

This will fail because you need to write the async keyword as shown below. You can see I put it after protected and before override.

```
        protected async override Task<bool> ShouldMakeADecision()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to expose an asynchronous wrapper for a synchronous method. This is not recommended, and you can read the reasons here: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

If you still insist on doing it, here is how it can be done:

```
private Task<bool> RefreshContactsAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            // Run the query
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Notice the absence of the `async` and `await` keywords. We just use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) overload that takes a `Func<TResult>` parameter, and returns a `Task<TResult>`. The `TResult` in this case is of type `bool`.

What you should do instead? Simply make your `RefreshContacts` method synchronous:

```
private bool RefreshContacts()
{
    try
    {
        // Run the query
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

...and wrap it in `Task.Run` at the calling site:

```
bool success = await Task.Run(() => RefreshContacts());
```

This way nobody is going to get the false impression that they are calling a genuinely asynchronous method (a method that [doesn't run on a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)). The intent is clear: a synchronous method is offloaded to the `ThreadPool`, most probably for the reason of keeping the UI responsive.